# Store the output of results.each into array in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, mysql2

Code:

```
 {   db = Mysql2::Client.new( :host => 'localhost', :username => 'username',
  password => 'password', :database => 'database')

results = db.query("select * from users where exported is not TRUE OR 
  NULL").each(:as => :array)

results.each { | row | puts row[1]}
```

The `results.each` line outputs outputs company data, and I want to use each line as an input within an API call. Any ideas as how to do this? Each row should populate an attribute like below.

```
"requested_item_value_attributes" => {
    "employee_first_name_6000555821" => 'results.each { | row | puts row[0]}',
    "employee_last_name_6000555821" => "results.each { | row | puts row[1]}",
    "hiring_manager_6000555821" => "results.each { | row | puts row[2]}",
    "job_title" => "results.each { | row | puts row[3]}",
    "start_date" => "#results.each { | row | puts row[4]}"
  }
```

Comment: If you want to store the results of a collection iteration use map/collect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`] to map the `results` to an array:

```
results.map do |row|
  "requested_item_value_attributes" => {
    "employee_first_name_6000555821" => row[0],
    "employee_last_name_6000555821" => row[1],
    "hiring_manager_6000555821" => row[2],
    "job_title" => row[3],
    "start_date" => row[4]
  }
}
```

or, even better:

```
results.map do |row|
  "requested_item_value_attributes" => 
    %w[
      employee_first_name_6000555821,
      employee_last_name_6000555821,
      hiring_manager_6000555821,
      job_title,
      start_date
    ].zip(row.take(5)).to_h
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
nameArray = Array.new
nameArray.push(nameToSave)
```

to add the variable `nameToSave` to the end of the array `nameArray`.
Just call `push` for each of your results and you have an array with all your names from your query.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `query` method second argument.

```
results = []
db.query('SELECT * FROM table', results)
```